# Occasional 404 response Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have deployed an Elixir/Phoenix web app on Heroku 2x instance, the backend is in Postgres. The app works fine most of the time but every now and then it returns `no such app` I am not able to figure out, why is it happening. I have checked the logs and metrics but nothing is helping. In fact, no logging happens when such errors are happening. It feels as if temporarily the DNS resolver on their side has crashed. I haven't added any custom domain and using the default domain name provided by Heroku.

Comment: Heroku doesn't provide external DNS services, so I'd be looking at *your* DNS. Heroku's internal DNS crashing would be extremely noticeable.

Comment: I am using the default domain name they provide. Also, I would like to mention that the app is deployed in EU. A similar instance deployed in US works fine.